# How to dynamically create and delete view when user clicks on button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

Please go through this scenario.

1. In a `UIViewController` there is a `UIScrollView` and inside it there is `UIView` and a `UIButton`. When a user taps on the `UIButton`, a new `UIView` should be added with the same *x*, *invialViewWidth + 30*, *width*, *height* and a `UIButton`.
2. If a user clicks the second `UIButton`, a new 3rd `UIView` with a third `UIButton` must be created. Similarly, you have to create a *n* number of views.
3. Inside the views there will be another `UIButton` *delete*. When it is clicked, the `UIView` should be removed from the `UIScrollView`.

For example, if you want to delete the 5th `UIView` then you should click on the delete `UIButton` which is in the 5th `UIView`.

I have gone through lot of questions but I haven't gotten a correct answer.

Comment: you should prefer `UITableView`

Comment: @matt  I have to use only scrollview

Comment: @danh I think this is new question,I dont find any duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom view which will contain two Buttons add and delete. You can do something like this:

```
-(UIView *)getNewViewWithTag:(NSInteger )tag{
        UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];//Set appropriate frame
        UIButton *addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        addButton.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,50,50); //Set appropriate frame
        addButton.tag = tag;
        [addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addNewView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [containerView addSubview:addButton];

        UIButton *deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        deleteButton.frame = CGRectMake(50,0,50,50); //Set appropriate frame
        deleteButton.tag = tag;
        [deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [containerView addSubview:deleteButton];
        containerView.tag = tag;
        return containerView;
    }
    -(void)addNewView:(id)button{
        NSInteger tag = [button tag];
        UIView *view = [self getNewViewWithTag:tag+1];
        //set appropriate frame
        [scrollView addSubview: view];
    }
    -(void)deleteView:(id)button{
        NSInteger tag = [button tag];
        UIView *viewToDelete = [scrollView viewWithTag:tag];
        [viewToDelete removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response,I  will check and let you know

Comment: @Hi rahul ,there is some problem in detecting the views,the problem is if you press delete button in 5th view the 5th view must delete not 4 th view.

Comment: one more is if click add button first view second must create and the add button in the first view must hidden

Comment: if you delete the meddle  view then how to rearrange the views.